# Mongoose can't stop query logging

Tags: mongodb, debugging, logging, mongoose

I recently updated to Mongoose 4, and now mongoose logs all of my queries in this format:

> Mongoose: repostevents.find({ day: { '$gt': new Date("Sun, 13 Nov 2016
>   22:16:22 GMT") }, completed: false, userID: 143155925 }, { fields:
>   undefined })

I want to turn off these logs.

I have tried the recommended solutions:

```
mongoose.set('debug', false);
```

and

```
mongoose.set('debug', function(collectionName, method, query, doc) {});
```

which change nothing.

These log messages are getting really annoying because I run large batch queries on my database which floods my log files with useless query logs.

Comment: Perhaps you're enabling logging somewhere else in your code. I don't see any logging with Mongoose 4.6.7 unless I explicitly enable it with `mongoose.set('debug', true);`

Answer (score 2):

JohnnyHK was correct in his comment. After doing a search, I found that there were several locations where another developer had written:

```
mongoose.set('debug',true);
```

I should have asked the other developer or done a full project search.

Answer (score 1):

I could not turn off the logs. Although I used the command to search:

```
grep -ri "goose.set" ~/
```

Command showed all the references, wiping them it unfortunately did not help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Check and remove debug true in

```
require('mongoose').set('debug', true)
```

Comment: Thanks Koby for improvising. This was my first attempt to answer here. Will keep this in mind